# Browser doesn't display newlines when using "\n".join() in Django

Tags: python, django

My code in Django is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Post

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    list_posts = Post.objects.order_by('-publish')[:5]
    output = ',\n'.join([p.slug for p in list_posts])
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

The view runs without errors, but I do not see the newlines in the browser.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRKeC.png)

Comment: Please edit your question, and give a bit more information on what you are trying to achieve, what steps you took and particularly what "run is True but don't run  ',\n'" is supposed to mean.

Comment: Also, it's better to post your results as text as well, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the page source in your browser, it will contain `\n`, but your browser will display these as regular spaces.

You can use a `<br>` tag if you want your browser to display each slug on a new line.

```
output = '<br>'.join([p.slug for p in list_posts])
```